# Selecting first part of a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the process of making a program, I came across the need to read the first value of a [text file](http://pastebin.com/Xrm015Gw). I have tried to put each value onto it's own line and read the first line such as in this code, but it would never load the part of the text file I wanted shown in this code:

```
l = open('output.txt').read()

words = l.split()

for word in words:
    print(word)

open("output.txt", 'wt').write(l)


with open('output.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           print(word)

open("output.txt", 'wt').write(word)

q = open("output.txt")

for x, line in enumerate(q):
    if x == 0:
        print (line)
```

How am I able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Store the contents one element a line and then do this

```
with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
    data = next(in_file)
```

now `data` will have the first line.

This works because [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function returns an object of `file` type, which is iterable. So, we iterate it with [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) function to get the first line.

Answer (score 0):

If you have every content in separate lines in the text file then you can try:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
```

here `data` is a list which contains the content of the text file extracted line by line

for eg: the text file contains data like

> Lamborghini Gallardo
>
> Audi
>
> Ferrari

then the above code will give: `data=['Lamborghini Gallardo', 'Audi', 'Ferrari']`